# Flyway generate different checksums from same migration script

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, flyway

I have Flyway installed on my SpringBoot app, and the when I start the app locally it generates a certain checksum.
However when I start it in production (AWS) I get different checksum.
The migration script is the same in both cases.

Does Flyway calculate different checksums in different environments?

Comment: you can get more info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267584/2551236

Comment: @Vihar this doesn't help with my question.

Comment: Read about CRC that is your answer.